# Send mysql dump to amazon S3

Tags: database, amazon-s3, backup, mysql

I want to do a simple full backup of my mysql database to S3 once or twice a day.  So I can execute mysqldump in a cron task.  What's the easiest way to send that dump to amazon S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd
If you are on Linux, it is probably included in your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Depends your OS.
I think use SSH (Winscp/scp) it's a good idea.

Comment: linux and I want to include the sending to S3 in the cron task.

Comment: So after mysqldump, use command scp ~/backup/mysqldump1 username@ho.st:/etc/mysql/backup